# On page load, async ajax call to load div content(html and js and css) result in deprecated error in chrome 80

Tags: google-chrome, deprecated, synchronous

On page load, async ajax call to load div(tab) content(html and js and css) result in   "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience." in chrome 80.
 First time this problem happened. Second time onwards on click to div(tab) this error is not happening. jquery version is 1.12.3. Tried with setTimeout,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
                  url: 'tabPage',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  async: true,
       data:'tabId=1&searchedEmpUserId='+searchedEmpUserId+'&menuId='+menuId,
                  success: function(data) {
               // load content from file into #content-holder
                $('#content-holder').html(data);
                 }});}
```

... but same error is coming.
Tried with

```
$("#content-holder").load('tabPage?tabId='+tabId+'&searchedEmpUserId='+searchedEmpUserId+'&menuId='+menuId, function(){
                unBlockUI();
            });
```

..that also same error. If HTML response text is not set then only error is not coming.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please properly format your code using the code button option. Also make sure the code samples are complete or note where you excluded code.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from dig down the issue, ajax call is asynchronous but html() or load() is synchronous. So jquery send method call has to change so that async call can be done by default. So async param is replaced with async || true in jquery 1.12.3 min js. It worked for me.